# wavelet filter modifies the original image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter

Hi I am Trying to get denoised image..Step are as below---

1. `EXTRACTPRNU(I)`
2. Apply a wavelet decomposition in 4 levels to I
3. foreach wavelet decomposition level do
4. foreach component c ∈ {H, V, D} do
5. Compute the local variance;
6. Compute noiseless wavelet components applying the Wiener filter to the variance;
7. Obtain I clean by applying the inverse wavelet transform with clean components calculated;

But Denoised image is altered. The image shows the problem

[image: Image showing effects]

I've also reported this on [Matlab Central](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/181200-wavelet-filter-modifies-the-original-image)

Comment: You should ideally give the actual code that you are using (or even better, a smaller, self-contained version which exhibits the same problem) instead of the pseodocode - this will help people to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yeah Its true but code is big . Could you please suggest me how to upload it ??  @chthonicdaemon

Comment: @Luky the code is proably big yeah, but it looks like you are doing some step wrongly. Probably no the theory but just some mistake somewhere.

Comment: I suggest using one of the built-in images (so `im = imread('board.tif')` for example) and trimming your code down to the smallest reproduction so that anyone can just copy-paste your code to see the result. Even if the code is quite big, if it's copy-pasteable it's not so bad.

Comment: Please follow the link.....Its for calculating the local variance

https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/181200-wavelet-filter-modifies-the-original-image

Comment: Could You please suggest something ??  @AnderBiguri

Comment: @Luky Yes! I suggest that you post a minimum working example.